# File operations in C on different architectures

Tags: c++, c, memory, endianness, low-level

As a research project we are writing an abstraction layer on top of the standard C (BINARY) file handling library (stdio), by providing a few extra functions for file handling with transactions.

The workflow is the following:

- user opens a file with our API (or with the standard `fopen`). Both return `FILE*`. File is open in BINARY mode!
- user writes data to the file using standard library commands (such as `fwrite`)
- user opens a transaction on the opened file using our API: `TRANSACTION a = trans_start(FILE* )`
- user sets data validators for the `TRANSACTION` object (`set_validator(TRANSACTION, int(*)(char*))`
- user "writes" data to the file using our own API (`int trans_write_string(TRANSACTION*, char*, length)`

  - in reality this "write" puts its data in the memory for the validators defined above, which might do operations on the data and set some flags somewhere... not relevant to the question.
- user uses `trans_commit(TRANSACTION)` in order to actually write the data to the file. Now, depending on the flags set by the validators, this might NOT write the data to the file, but report an error to the user (which programatically can be resolved. ... not so relevant to the question).
- user closes file using standard API `fclose`.

Till now we have only the string handling method of the API (`trans_write_string`), which works nicely. It constructs its own in memory data buffer, modifies stuff if required, calls validators, etc... on consecutive calls it appends the new data into its internal memory buffer, handles allocation, etc... and at a successful commit it writes the data to the file using `fwrite` (Yes, this is mostly a C project, however C++ answers will not be excluded either).

But now we want to (... have to) expand the API to be able to write also numbers (16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit) and also floats too... in a very similar way that the standard `C` stdio API does it. Using the already existing implementation for the string, this assumes that we have a data buffer in the memory, which holds `N` bytes of characters (the string itself), the we might need to have 2 bytes for a 16 bit value then another `M` bytes for another string, the 8 bytes for a 64 bit value, the 2 bytes for a 16 bit value, etc...

We got stuck at the point of "how to represent a number in the file in order to be readable by someone else too who uses a different computer/architecture/os/endianness".

Inserting the number in the memory stream theoretically is possible via a casting to char (`char* addr = &my_16bit_int`), and place `*(addr)` and `*(addr + 1)` to the required address (ie: after the `N` characters of the string) and writing it to the file is also possible, but what if I want to read the resulting file on a different architecture where the endiannes is different? And what if the "other" computer is only a 16 bit ancient piece of pile of metal? What would happen in that case to the 64 bit values written in the file?

What good practices are there for resolving this kind of issues?

**EDIT**: The target file must be binary it will be accompanied by a text file (XML) describing its format (such as: `N` 8 byte characters, `1` 16 bit value, etc..) (this text file is generated based on the output of our beloved validators). The validator "says" something like, YES, I accept this 16 bit value, no I reject this long string, etc... and someone else is creating a data format XML based on this "output".

**EDIT2**: Yes, we need to share the file across various platforms, even huge 20 year old fridge size boxes :)

**EDIT3**: Yes, we need float too!

Comment: Do you need to share your files across platforms ? If you don't, then this is no issue. If you do, you need to come up with and describe your file format - once that is described, it is rather easy to make somewhat platform independent code to read/write integers. (and a bit harder for floating point..). You also need to define the scope of your library - it might not be reasonable to create one library for this which covers all past and future platforms/architectures and operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting is not sufficient, I think the sockets method `htons` and `htonl` will be sufficient solution for int16 and int32. for int64 you should build it yourself, since there is no  official method:

Note that all the functions are reversing the bytes order **only if needed**, so you can also use the same method in order to 'fix' a number back to normal.

```
typedef union{
    unsigned char c[2];
    unsigned short s;
}U2;

//you can use the standard htons or this
unsigned short htons(unsigned short s)
{
    U2 mask,res;
    unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)&s; 
    mask.s = 0x0001;
    res.c[mask.c[0]] = p[0];
    res.c[mask.c[1]] = p[1];
    return res.s;
}

//the same for 4 bytes
typedef union{
    unsigned char c[4];
    unsigned short s[2];
    unsigned long l;
}U4;

//you can use the standard htonl or this
unsigned long htonl(unsigned long l)
{
    U4 mask,res;
    unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)&l; 
    mask.l = 0x00010203;
    res.c[mask.c[0]] = p[0];
    res.c[mask.c[1]] = p[1];
    res.c[mask.c[2]] = p[2];
    res.c[mask.c[3]] = p[3];
    return res.l;
}

typedef union{
    unsigned char c[8];
    unsigned char c2[2][4];
    unsigned short s[4];    
    unsigned long l[2];
    unsigned long long ll; 
}U8; 

//for int64 you can use the int64 and do the same, or you can to do it with 2*4 like i did
//you can give a void pointer as well.. 
unsigned long long htonll(unsigned long long ll)//void htonll(void* arg, void* result)
{
    U2 mask1;
    U4 mask2;
    U8 res;

    unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)&ll; //or (unsigned char*)arg   
    mask1.s = 0x0001;
    mask2.l = 0x00010203;
    //I didn't use the int64 for convertion 
    res.c2[mask1.c[0]][mask2.c[0]] = p[0];
    res.c2[mask1.c[0]][mask2.c[1]] = p[1];
    res.c2[mask1.c[0]][mask2.c[2]] = p[2];
    res.c2[mask1.c[0]][mask2.c[3]] = p[3];
    res.c2[mask1.c[1]][mask2.c[0]] = p[4];
    res.c2[mask1.c[1]][mask2.c[1]] = p[5];
    res.c2[mask1.c[1]][mask2.c[2]] = p[6];
    res.c2[mask1.c[1]][mask2.c[3]] = p[7];

    //memcpy(result,res.c,8);
    return res.ll;
}
//or if you want to use the htonl:
unsigned long long htonll2(unsigned long long ll)
{
    U2 mask1;
    U8 res;
    mask1.s = 0x0001;
    unsigned long* p = (unsigned long*)&ll;
    res.l[0] = htonl(p[mask1.c[0]]);
    res.l[1] = htonl(p[mask1.c[1]]);
    return res.ll;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned short s = 0x1122;
    cout<<hex<<htons(s)<<endl;
    unsigned long l = 0x11223344;
    cout<<hex<<htonl(l)<<endl;
    unsigned long long ll=0x1122334455667788;
    cout<<hex<<htonll(ll)<<endl;
    cout<<hex<<htonll2(ll)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a format, or choose an existing binary
format like XDR, and read and write it.  Thus, for example, to
write a 32 bit integer in XDR:

```
void
write32Bits( FILE* dest, uint_least32_t value )
{
    putc( (value >> 24) & 0xFF, dest );
    putc( (value >> 16) & 0xFF, dest );
    putc( (value >>  8) & 0xFF, dest );
    putc( (value      ) & 0xFF, dest );
}
```

Floating point is more complicated, but if you're willing to
restrict your platforms to those supporting IEEE float, you can
type pun `float` to `uint32_t` and `double` to `uint64_t`, and
output it as an unsigned int.  Similarly, if you restrict
yourself to 2's complement machines with a 32 bit integral type,
you can also use the shift and mask procedure above for signed
values (and the integral types would be `uint32_t` and
`int32_t`).

With regards to portability: I think that IEEE is universal,
except for mainframes, and 2's complement is universal except
for very exotic mainframes.  (IBM mainframes are 2's complement,
but not IEEE.  Unisys mainframes are not 2's complement, and
don't have a 32 bit integral type.  I'm not sure what other
mainframes are still in existance, but in the past, there were
all sorts of exotics.)

Comment: Actually for us the writing of the data is the easy part, since we have a long string, and just fwrite... Constructing the long string is the problematic part :)

Comment: @fritzone Which is probably the better way to go;-).  Instead of `putc`, just append the byte to the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using glibc then you can use its functions for le <-> be transformations from "endian.h":

```
SYNOPSIS
   #define _BSD_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
   #include <endian.h>

   uint16_t htobe16(uint16_t host_16bits);
   uint16_t htole16(uint16_t host_16bits);
   uint16_t be16toh(uint16_t big_endian_16bits);
   uint16_t le16toh(uint16_t little_endian_16bits);

   uint32_t htobe32(uint32_t host_32bits);
   uint32_t htole32(uint32_t host_32bits);
   uint32_t be32toh(uint32_t big_endian_32bits);
   uint32_t le32toh(uint32_t little_endian_32bits);

   uint64_t htobe64(uint64_t host_64bits);
   uint64_t htole64(uint64_t host_64bits);
   uint64_t be64toh(uint64_t big_endian_64bits);
   uint64_t le64toh(uint64_t little_endian_64bits);
```

If you are not using glibc then you can just have a look at glibc-2.18/bits/byteswap.h